# Clarification about IntentService

Tags: android, service, intentservice

I need some explanations about `IntentService`. I have to monitor location in background. I know how to receive location updates while the app is running, but my question is: should I put all the code I used before, in the `IntentService`?

For example, if I want to monitor the location changes, and apply some changes when the location is actually changed (not to the app UI, but to the system, for example the phone wallpaper), should I do it directly in the `IntentService`?

Comment: please elaborate more

Comment: I need to change the phone wallpaper based on the location changes. So i need a service to monitor location. Should I simply put in the service the code I normally use in an app to monitor location or should I follow some other procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Service (Sticky)` rather using `IntentService`Because `IntentService` is creates an internal worker Thread itself and as soon as task within `IntentService` completed its stop itself but in your case you need get Location continuously in background.
So in this case you should crate `service` with `Thread` in side your Service and its working all time.

Comment: he might be using pending intent for location

Comment: But If we create `bindService` we can update `UI` in very good manner.

Comment: I don't want to update the UI of the app. I only want to use a web api, retrieve the image and change the wallpaper.

Comment: if you want to change wallpaper for any event like push notification then you can use `IntentService`  for one time work .